# Why is Jenkins job not failing?

Tags: shell, jenkins

When the job is ran, a script is executed. And it is supposed to exit with code 2 but it is exiting with code 0.

In the script I have:

```
ssh User@$myHost ant start
if [ ! $? = 0 ] ; then
    echo "*** Failed to start the application." 
    exit 2
fi
```

And I get in the console:

```
*** Failed to start the application.
*** rm -rf /opt/hudson/node2/Appi/*
*** exit 0
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It is not exiting with code 2 as it should..but it echos "Failed to start the application."

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `*** rm -rf /opt/hudson/node2/Appi/*` this statement is getting logged on console...how ? Are you sure the code included in question is same as in your jenkins config ?

Comment: I agree with @KishanSarsechaGajjar, you are not providing the whole script... difficult to guess at the answer without that

Comment: rm -rf /opt/hudson/node2/Appi/* is a command of a script, that calls another script where the If statement is located.

Comment: Basically I am trying to exit 2 from a secondary script, where the if statement posted is located.

Comment: So your build step executes *1st* script, which then calls *2nd* script. Your *2nd* script exits with `exit 2` and the control returns to *1st* script. Your *1st* script (the one you haven't posted) is the one that is not handling the exit code of the *2nd* script. Please post the other script. Exiting the *2nd* script (which seems to have worked fine) does not terminate control of the *1st* script.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, `$? = 0` is a string comparison. You should use `$? -eq 0` for a true arithmetic comparison.

Second, where is the `rm -rf` coming from? It is not in the script you provided. Is there another **Execute Shell** build step with that command?

Please paste the whole script(s)

*Based on the assumptions, without seeing the full scripts:*

### first_script.sh

```
# some stuff
# ...

# call second script, store exit code
./second_script.sh
retVal=$?

# Handle exit code of second script
if [ ! $retVal -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "** Second script failed, so I am failing too with same code"
    exit $retVal
fi

# some more stuff
# ...
rm -rf /opt/hudson/node2/Appi/*
exit 0
```

### second_script.sh

```
ssh User@$myHost ant start
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "*** Failed to start the application." 
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: The string "[ ! $? = 0 ]" executes the POSIX test(1) utility to check the arguments for inequality as strings: it is not an assignment statement.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson From `man bash` snippet: `string1 == string2. True if the strings are equal. = may be used in place of == for strict POSIX compliance.` While a single `=` *may* be used, it is not ideal for numeric comparison (and exit code is a **numeric** comparison). The `-eq` is an **arithmetic binary operator** while `=` and `==` are *string operators*. Exit code from `$?` is a numeric value, and should be treated as such. Just cause "bash" is not strong typed, does not mean you should resolve to weak programming practices and shortcuts.

Comment: So with that in-mind, what is wrong with *recommending* to use true **arithmetic binary operator** and what is wrong with the whole answer?

Comment: My point is that it's not an assignment expression as you asserted. That is all.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson well technically I said that `$? = 0` is an assignment, and it is true, as I did not mention `[` or `test` in that sentence. Nonetheless, you cannot argue that suggesting to use `-eq` for arithmetic comparison is wrong in any way. Nor are you pointing out anything wrong with the rest of the answer. I would appreciate if you remove the downvote. I will remove the "offending" `is an assignment` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing complete script code, so it is not possible to guess what you are doing,
But there is a solution you can implement.

Manage a variable holding the value of exit value and write `exit $VAR` at end of your script from where you want to return exit value.

Example :

```
RET_VAL=0 # Default return value is 0

ssh User@$myHost ant start
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then # Your script is not correct here.
    echo "*** Failed to start the application." 
    RET_VAL=2
fi

....
# Execute whatever you want and manage value of RET_VAL according to results.
...
return $RET_VAL # This must be last statement of your jenkins configuration script.
```

And please correct errors in your script, as mentioned in answer of @Slav.